# How do I run a program written in c on a computer which has no compiler

Tags: c

This a program to calculate GPA. The program is running properly. How can I run this program on a computer which has no compiler installed.?
How do I run this program on a pc which has no compiler?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

  int main() {
        char str[100], ch;
        int i, grade[8];
        float credit[8], gpa = 0.0, totCredit = 0.0;

        /* get the letter grade and credits from the user */
        printf("Letter Grade and Credits for each subject:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                printf("Subject %d(Grade|Credit):", i + 1);
                ch = getchar();
                grade[i] = ch;
                scanf("%f", &credit[i]);
                getchar();
        }

        /* print the input grades and credits */
        printf("\nSubject | Grade | Credit\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                printf("   %d    |  %c    | %.1f\n", i + 1, grade[i], credit[i]);
        }

        /* calculate gpa value */
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                switch (grade[i]) {
                        case 'S':
                                gpa = gpa + 10 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;
                        case 'A':
                                gpa = gpa + 9 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        case 'B':
                                gpa = gpa + 8 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        case 'C':
                                gpa = gpa + 7 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        case 'D':
                                gpa = gpa + 6 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        case 'E':
                                gpa = gpa + 5 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        case 'F':
                                gpa = gpa + 4 * credit[i];
                                totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                                break;

                        default:
                                printf("Given Wrong grade!!\n");
                                exit(0);

                }
        }
        printf("GPA: %.1f\tcredit: %.1f\n", gpa, totCredit);
        gpa = gpa / totCredit;
        printf("GPA for your score: %.2f\n", gpa);
        return 0;
  }
```

This a program to calculate GPA. The program is running properly. How can I run this program on a computer which has no compiler installed.?
How do I run this program on a pc which has no compiler?

Comment: You can't, compile it in another computer.

Comment: use an online compiler, like ideone.

Comment: Any other way. Like a software?

Comment: The software called *compiler*.

Comment: If it's the same kind of PC as the one that you used to compile it, then you could compile it on the first one and then run it on the second one

Comment: Install a C compiler.

Comment: @mikeyq6 You can even *cross-compile* it on a different kind PC...

Comment: BTW, if your `totCredit` is zero, you will get division by zero...

Comment: How do you think all the programs you have on your Windows or Linux or OSX system were made? They were built (in C or C++ or some other language) on another computer which *have* a compiler, and then you just "copy" the program and run on your computer without compiler.

Comment: You also need to consider how to distribute the standard libraries. Deploying an app deserves a separate question.

Comment: @user3528438 No need for statically linked binary..

Comment: If the second machine is the same platform as what you compiled your code on (same OS, same chip architecture, etc.), then all you need to do is copy the executable file (that is, the binary file generated by your compiler) to that second machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I run this program on a pc which has no compiler?

I can think of two ways:

1. Compile the program an a different pc with the same environment. Copy the executable and then run it.
2. Cross compile the program an a different pc with different environment, making sure that settings for cross compiling match the target pc. Copy the executable and then run it.

Comment: Another way would be to establish a remote session (telnet?) to a computer with compiler, compile it there and run it there. Perhaps it would be good enough for the OP...